# Passing function pointer in Dlang

Tags: function, d

I'm trying to run OpenGL sample with Dlang.

```d
void onError(int code, const(char)* text) nothrow
{
}
```

Usage:

```d
glfwSetErrorCallback(&onError);
```

Binding code:

```d
__gshared {

    da_glfwSetErrorCallback glfwSetErrorCallback;
    
    ...

extern( C ) @    nogc nothrow {

    alias da_glfwSetErrorCallback = GLFWerrorfun function( GLFWerrorfun );

    ...

    alias GLFWerrorfun = void function( int, const( char )* );
```

And i get the following compiler error:

```
Error: function pointer glfwSetErrorCallback (extern (C) void function(int, const(char)*) nothrow) is not callable using argument types (void function(int code, const(char)* text) nothrow)
```

Compiler: 2.065.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [interfacing to C guidelines](http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html) on callbacks:

> D can easily call C callbacks (function pointers), and C can call callbacks provided by D code if the callback is an extern(C) function, or some other linkage that both sides have agreed to (e.g. extern(Windows)).

So I think you need your `onError` function to be declared as `extern(C)` in order for it to match the type signature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a function prototype in D code:

```d
// Function prototypes
extern (C) void onError(int, const(char)*) nothrow

extern (C) void onError(int code, const(char)* text) nothrow
{
   //your code
}
```

Notice, that in the prototype there are only types.